# Reverse of Number.format()?

Tags: formatting, numbers, mootools, mootools-more

In MooTools More (1.4), there is a `Number.format()` function which takes a number and converts to a readable format, such as...

```
"5,003.2" === (5003.2).format()
```

.. considering the currently set `Locale`.

My question: Is there a possibility to have the reverse effect happen, e.g. for storing the plain numbers in a database? Something like:

```
5003.2 === "5,003.2".reverseformat()
```

Or do I have to use RegEx?

Comment: There isn't one that is readily available and it's not trivial. The string you have there is easy to do via regex but regex does not really tell you what the locale is and what the custom is. For instance, seeing `5,300` in the UK should go to a cool `5300`. in EU, it will often mean `5.3`. Trusting client locale is also falsy, ppl travel with laptops...

Comment: If I had a number I would store and use the number as a number. The string created from "format" is only presentation. If you want to have the value in the "DOM" you could use store/retrieve instead. For example: `element.store('myValue', 5003.2)` and `element.retrieve('myValue')` to use it.

Comment: Alright, that's a good hint. I solved it differently, but yeah..

Comment: @DimitarChristoff could you post your comment as an answer, I will then accept it for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't one that is readily available and it's not trivial. The string you have there is easy to do via regex but regex does not really tell you what the Locale is and what the custom format looks like.

For instance, seeing `5,300` in the UK should go to a cool `5300`. In EU, it will often mean rounding to `5.3`.

Having said that, see http://josscrowcroft.github.com/accounting.js/

it also supports `unformat` which can bring it back.

Trusting client Locale is general can also be `falsy`, people travel with laptops... Though this is more applicable to Locale time/timezone stuff.